# Calendar Not Showing events

Tags: iphone, ios, calendar

I updated my iPhone 4 to iOS 7 and now my calendar is not working.

When I try to put an event in and press done it does not show in the phone's calendar, but it does show in the iCloud calendar.

Comment: is your sync broken ?

Answer (score 1):

Alan R, I think your sync is broken.

Taken from this article : http://email.about.com/od/googlecalendartips/qt/Sync_Google_Calendar_and_iPhone_Calendar.htm

I think you should sync a Google Calendar with iPhone Calendar, it works best!

> Make sure you have no conflicting iCal, Exchange or Outlook calendars with which to synchronize. iPhone Calendar can only sync with one calendaring source.
>   Go to Google Sync in iPhone Safari.
>   Tap your iPhone under Manage devices.
>   Make sure all calendars you want to sync are checked.
>   Tap Save.
>   Press the Home button.
>   Tap Settings on the Home screen.
>   Go to Mail, Contacts, Calendars.
>   Tap Add Account... under Accounts.
>   Choose Microsoft Exchange.
>   Enter your Gmail address under Email.
>   Enter "m.google.com" (not including the quotation marks) under Domain.
>   Tap your full Gmail address under Username.
>   Enter your Google Calendar password under Password.
>   Optionally, tap "Google Calendar" under Description.
>   Tap Next.
>   Enter "m.google.com" under Server.
>   Tap Next again.
>   Make sure Calendars is ON.
>   Turn ON Mail to enable push Gmail in iPhone Mail.
>   Turn ON Contacts only if you have copied your existing contacts to Gmail. Otherwise, your existing iPhone contacts will be replaced with your Gmail address book contents.
>   Tap Done.

Comment: did not do it this way but followed the basic structure and it worked!! So thanks

Comment: Alan R, if you think this is the perfect answer, i think you should check this answer.